# How to edit h5 files with h5py?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, h5py

**The question on overwrite array using h5py did not solve my problem.**
I want to edit the array values of a VGG16 model.

```
f = h5py.File('C:/Users/yash/.keras/models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_2.h5', mode = 'a')
ab = list(h5py.AttributeManager.keys(f))
print(list(f.attrs.keys()))
print(ab)
```

The code above returns:

```
['layer_names']


['block1_conv1', 'block1_conv2', 'block1_pool', 'block2_conv1', 'block2_conv2', 'block2_pool', 'block3_conv1', 'block3_conv2', 'block3_conv3', 
'block3_pool', 'block4_conv1', 'block4_conv2', 'block4_conv3', 'block4_pool',
'block5_conv1', 'block5_conv2', 'block5_conv3', 'block5_pool', 'fc1', 'fc2', 

'flatten', 'predictions']
```

After using this code:
`print(f.attrs['layer_names'])`

I get the following:

```
[b'block1_conv1' b'block1_conv2' b'block1_pool' b'block2_conv1'
 b'block2_conv2' b'block2_pool' b'block3_conv1' b'block3_conv2'
 b'block3_conv3' b'block3_pool' b'block4_conv1' b'block4_conv2'
 b'block4_conv3' b'block4_pool' b'block5_conv1' b'block5_conv2'
 b'block5_conv3' b'block5_pool' b'flatten' b'fc1' b'fc2' b'predictions']
```

How can i change the values that are contained within the `f.attrs['layer_names']`? I am not able to edit them mainly because using:
`print(f.attrs['layer_names/block1_conv1'])` returns an error.

There is a weight and bias matrix inside every block(n)_conv(n).

I want to change those values.

I am doing this in python 3, and no documentation helped me in editing these values. Mostly because i am unable to access these without using this code:

```
layer = h5py.AttributeManager.get(f, key = str(layerstringlist[i]))
 nplayer = np.asarray(list(layer))
```

`layerstringlist` is a list of this manner:

```
['block1_conv1/block1_conv1_W_1:0', 'block1_conv1/block1_conv1_b_1:0', .....
'predictions/predictions_W_1:0', 'predictions/predictions_b_1:0']
```

This returns it correctly, but i am unable to save the modified h5 file because i do not know how to reference it in python 3.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't you access things with `f.attrs['layer_names'][0]`, `f.attrs['layer_names'][1]` etc?

Comment: I tried it. f.attrs['layer_names'][0][:] returns b'block1_conv1'. Basically it is a list, which is being indexed by using the [0]. I need to access the group inside 'block1_conv1' so i can use that matrix and edit it. Any tips?

Comment: The string is a bytes sequence so yes, you're seeing the (ASCII) value of the character at that position (107 for `c`). But indeed, that doesn't help you, as it only accesses the names of the layers, not their data.

Comment: I think the reason i am not able to access the sub branches is because their name is a byte string, however the root (layer_names) is just a string. So using this: f.attrs['layer_names/block1_conv1'] isnt working. Do you have any tips to circumvent this issue? Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear to me, though, why you can't access them directly: `f['block1_conv1']`? Since `'layer_names'` is only a key in the attribute of `f`. You should also look at [`f.keys()`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#Group.keys) directly, not the one of `f.attrs`.

Comment: This works. f['block1_conv1/block1_conv1_W_1:0'] returns a <HDF5 dataset>. Can i simply equate it with a numpy array to set it as the array? Or does something else have to be done? I can't thank you enough for your help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen the use of `AttributeManager` before, perhaps because the documentation discourages its use, http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/attr.html#reference

With a file left over from other SO tests I get:

```
In [480]: list(h5py.AttributeManager.keys(f))
Out[480]: ['agroup', 'agroup1', 'agroup2', 'arr']
In [481]: list(f.attrs.keys())
Out[481]: []
In [482]: list(f.keys())
Out[482]: ['agroup', 'agroup1', 'agroup2', 'arr']
```

In this case I have not assigned any attributes to the file, hence `f.attrs.keys()` is empty.  It appears that your file has one attribute, 'layer_names'.  Its value is a list of names, which you list with `print(f.attrs['layer_names'])`.

The `AttributeManager` lists the groups and datasets, not the `attrs`.  I get the same list with `f.keys()`.

You should be access one of these groups or datasets with:

```
f['block1_conv1']
```

If this is a group you need to index down another layer.  If it is a dataset, read and write to it as described in http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data

I don't think the `f.attrs['layer_names']` list is of any use to you, since it has the same information as `list(f.keys()).

---

Based on your comment, `f['block1_conv1']` is a group, with contains several datasets.  These are equivalent ways of indexing a set:

```
f['block1_conv1/block1_conv1_W_1:0'] 
f['block1_conv1']['block1_conv1_W_1:0']
```

In my test file

```
In [483]: f['arr']
Out[483]: <HDF5 dataset "arr": shape (3,), type "|V31">
```

I can load the dataset into memory as an array with `value` or `[:]`:

```
In [485]: f['arr'].value
Out[485]: 
array([(123, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
       (  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)],
      dtype=[('Status', '<u8'), ('Segments', '<u4'), ('Characterized', '<u4'), ('More_Segments', '<u4'), ('ID', '<i4'), ('Releases', '<u2'), ('Type', 'u1'), ('Track', '<i4')])
In [486]: f['arr'][:]
Out[486]: 
array([(123, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
       (  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)],
      dtype=[('Status', '<u8'), ('Segments', '<u4'), ('Characterized', '<u4'), ('More_Segments', '<u4'), ('ID', '<i4'), ('Releases', '<u2'), ('Type', 'u1'), ('Track', '<i4')])
```

(sorry, this example is a complicated structured array.)

I can modify the values of this dataset just as I would modify an array of the same type and shape

```
In [487]: f['arr']['Status']
Out[487]: array([123,   1,   1], dtype=uint64)
In [488]: f['arr']['Status'] = [1,2,3]
```

I cannot replace it. `f['arr'] = np.arange(10)` gives me an error (name already exists). `f['arr'][:] = np.arange(10)` gives a different error (about incompatible shapes).

I could create a new dataset with a different name

```
In [492]: f.create_dataset('newarray', np.arange(10))
Out[492]: <HDF5 dataset "newarray": shape (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), type "<f4">
In [493]: list(f.keys())
Out[493]: ['agroup', 'agroup1', 'agroup2', 'arr', 'newarray']
```

I can delete a dataset with:

```
In [494]: del f['newarray']
In [495]: list(f.keys())
Out[495]: ['agroup', 'agroup1', 'agroup2', 'arr']
```

and define a new one with same name with:

```
In [500]: f.create_dataset('newarray', data=np.ones((3,4)))
Out[500]: <HDF5 dataset "newarray": shape (3, 4), type "<f8">
```

Comment: This works. f['block1_conv1/block1_conv1_W_1:0'] returns a <HDF5 dataset> which when converted to a list gives me the matrix i wanted. My question is, how can I change this matrix to another numpy array? (I want to commit the change to the h5 file in the end) Documentation made things over complicated for me so i ask you directly.
Thanks!

Comment: I added some examples of accessing and modifying datasets.

Comment: I saw what you have said, I tried: 
`replace = np.zeros(shape = np.asarray(list(f['block1_conv1/block1_conv1_W_1:0'])).shape)`

`f['block1_conv1/block1_conv1_W_1:0'] = replace`
It gives me : Unable to create link (name already exists). So the only way for me to do this is to delete that specific reference, and create a new reference: 
`f.create_dataset('block1_conv1/block1_conv1_W_1:0', replace)` after deleting that HDF5 object yes?