# How to properly open, read from and save to a single file in python 3 using H5py

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I am new to python and programming in gerneral and am probably making horrible mistakes. Thank you for any help. I want to to initialize a member of my class by loading either some hdf5 data prepared by someone else or by loading my own hdf5 files. I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import sys

class ashot:
    def __init__(self, path, load=False):
        if load is False:
            self.name = "_".join(re.findall(r"(\d+)_(\d+)/aa/shot_(\d+)", path)[0])
            f = h5py.File(path, "r")
            numpyarray = f["data/data"]
            self.array = numpyarray
        else:
            f = h5py.File(path, "a")
            self.array = f["array"]
            self.name = f["array"].attrs["name"]

    def saveshot(self):
        s = h5py.File(self.name+".h5", "a")
        s.create_dataset("array", data=self.array)
        s["array"].attrs["name"] = self.name
        s.close()
        return()
```

but if I run it using:

```
testshot = ashot("somepath to data storage")
testshot.saveshot()
loadshot = ashot("the path I stored the shot testshot", load = True)
loadshot.saveshot()
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "program path.py", line 191, in <module>
loadshot.saveshot()
File "program path.py", line 114, in saveshot
s.create_dataset("array", data=self.array)
File "C:\Users\Drossel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\group.py", line 109, in create_dataset
self[name] = dset
File "C:\Users\Drossel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\group.py", line 277, in __setitem__
h5o.link(obj.id, self.id, name, lcpl=lcpl, lapl=self._lapl
File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper
File "h5py\h5o.pyx", line 202, in h5py.h5o.link
RuntimeError: Unable to create link (name already exists)
```

I kinda get that I am trying to write to a file that is already open, but the same code usoing numpy.save and numpy.load works for some reason. I tried closing the file after assiningthe self.array, but then i get

```
NameError: name 'ashot' is not defined
```

Beacuse, I'm assuming, f is only a file handle at that point. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In `saveshot` you are opening the file with mode `"a"`, which let's you write (add/append) to an existing file. Presumably, the dataset "array" already exists in the file so you can't create it anew. Either use mode `"w"` to replace the existing file, or [`require_dataset`](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#Group.require_dataset) instead of `create_dataset`. (Mostly guesswork, I'm not much into h5py.)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunatly, both ideas didnt work out and ran into the same problem. Do you know if there is a way to open the file with a "with open" statement without losing the data saved in the attribute after the file handle is closed?

Comment: Could you change the example so we can run it with a simple copy-n-paste?

Comment: @hpaulj Do you still want me to change it or is it now unecessary since you have answered my question perfectly already?

Comment: You are fine.............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't allowed to create a dataset twice:

```
In [34]: F = h5py.File('testh546643026.h5','a')
In [35]: ds = F.create_dataset('tst',data=np.arange(3))
In [36]: F.close()
In [37]: F = h5py.File('testh546643026.h5','a')
In [38]: ds = F.create_dataset('tst',data=np.arange(3))
....
RuntimeError: Unable to create link (Name already exists)
```

`require` can fetch an existing dataset (or make a new one), but shape and dtype must match (see its docs):

```
In [41]: ds = F.require_dataset('tst',(3,),int)
In [42]: ds
Out[42]: <HDF5 dataset "tst": shape (3,), type "<i4">
In [43]: ds.value
Out[43]: array([0, 1, 2])
In [44]: ds[:]=np.ones((3,))
In [45]: ds.value
Out[45]: array([1, 1, 1])
```

If you want to freely replace an existing dataset you have to first delete it.

[How to edit h5 files with h5py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46121210/how-to-edit-h5-files-with-h5py)

Comment: awesome! this worked perfectly, I ended up deleting the old dataset and making a copy of it everytime I save. Thank you for your help and time!